# Use Lua To Open .chm At Defined Index Page

Tags: lua, chm

I wish to open a specific page within a .chm file from lua, but can not find any resources that would instruct me as to how how this task may be accomplished. If someone could provide some code that would open an index page named "Test2" in a file named "TestFile.chm" from lua I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate problems here. First, how to open a CHM file at all from Lua, and second, how to open it at a specific page.

The first is straightforward, making the assumption that you are on a Windows box and things are set up in the usual way. Given that, `os.execute("example.chm")` will launch the CHM file in the help viewer, and block until the viewer exits. To open it without blocking execution, you probably want to do `os.execute("start example.chm")`.

If you are not using Windows, then you will need to figure out the name of your preferred CHM viewer for your platform if the first method does not work.

To get a link to a specific page within a CHM, you will need to know the name of the page. This is not easy to discover unless you have access to the original sources to the CHM, or have HTML Help developer tools available to disassemble the CHM and inspect its content. Note that the page name might also include some path information that will need to match exactly. For best results, look in the help project's `HHP` file, in the `[FILES]` section, for the name of the desired page as known to the help system.

Given that name, invoke `hh.exe` something like this: `os.execute("start hh example.chm::/path/to/my/page.html")`.

Comment: The path of a specific page can also be found by right clicking on it and selecting Properties. Look at the "Adress (URL)" field; it's the part at the end after the "::" characters.Another way is to select the "Jump to URL" item in the HTML Help window menu (the menu you get when clicking on the caption icon on the top left)

Comment: @efotinis, Good to know. I'd forgotten about the property dialog, and I don't think I've ever noticed the Jump to URL item. Given the long and twisty nature of URLs inside the CHM, it is hard to imagine who the author of hh thought would be using that menu item...

Answer (score 0):

shell executing `ms_its://example.chm::/path/to/mypage.html` might also help