# .chm file opening at a given index page from Matlab

Tags: url, matlab, web, html-helper, chm

I am trying to open a specific page within a .chm file from a Matlab GUI with the `web` function. Following the instructions and comments found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097601/use-lua-to-open-chm-at-defined-index-page) I have got the url of the desired page (mk:@MSITStore:D:\POv9\Ayuda\ayuda.chm::/html/ayuda1.html). However, when I write the command I need at the prompt

```
web('mk:@MSITStore:D:\POv9\Ayuda\ayuda.chm::/html/ayuda1.html','-browser')
```

it does not work (nothing happens neither an error message). I also have tried the following:

- `web('D:\POv9\Ayuda\ayuda.chm::/html/ayuda1.html','-browser')`
- `web('ayuda.chm::/html/ayuda1.html','-browser')`

without success.

I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on windows this works:

```
!hh mk:@MSITStore:D:\POv9\Ayuda\ayuda.chm::/html/ayuda1.html
```

This opens the help file in the Microsoft Help Viewer at the specified page.